# Full table scan on mysql queries which have limit

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I have this simple query:

```
select * from wp_users limit 10
```

When I check the query cost, using EXPLAIN tool in MySQLWorkBench, I find **full table Scan**, while I limited query to 10 rows, without any condition.

Why it doesn't stop after 10th row?

Note : Number of rows is large enough to force "not use fullscan"

[image]

Comment: I suppose it means a full table scan is performed until the 10 rows is returned. (Can't be improved.)

Comment: Even if table has 500k rows, it should read all then return 10?

Comment: The query can not be scanned by an index since you don't query on one. So all data is considered for the result and 10 of those are returned. Did you notice any performance problems?

Comment: Also the result of this query is random .. As ANSI/ISO SQL standard have defined resultsets to be **orderless** without using a `ORDER BY` .. But also keep in mind that sorting non unique values still will be random in cases of "ties"

Comment: I have indexes over this table, you suggest sorting by one of them?

Comment: @RaymondNijland . . . It is not "random".  It is indeterminate and can vary from one execution to another.

Comment: *" It is not "random"* Yes i know @GordonLinoff  i know i should have said non deterministic (which more or less means "random") which i normally say ...

Comment: @RaymondNijland . . . "random" does have a specific meaning in analytics, so I'm wary of using it.